# Android Studio, Element path must be declared for FileProvider

Tags: android, android-studio

I rerally didn't want to ask this question, but I couldn't find any solutions.

In my manifest I have declared FileProvider:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

It requires `@xml/provider_paths` to work. In my resources folder I have created `provider_paths.xml` file and copy-pasted this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

However Android Studio IDE throws me that kind of error:

```
Element paths must be declared
```

My screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your `provider_paths.xml` goes in the `res/xml/` folder, not `values/`.

Comment: @MikeM. Could you write proper description as an answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Comment: It's cool. You can just accept sasikumar's answer, if you want, since they've corrected it. Thanks, though. Appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the provider_path.xml  from  values directory to 
 res/xml/provider_paths.xml

To specify the directories, start by creating the file filepaths.xml in the res/xml/ subdirectory of your project. In this file, specify the directories by adding an XML element for each directory.

Refer [Specify Sharable Directories](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html)

Comment: But anim and drawables are connected with images in views. How my paths for FIleProvider is connected to drawables?

Comment: Thanks for this. So why on earth would Android Studio, on choosing new XML, place it in /values instead of /xml? Makes my head explode.